# Haskell, consume non-blocking getLine

Tags: haskell, io, nonblocking

I'm looking for a method to read from stdin and after a while, if there is no input given, I want to skip that getLine.

I have this code which skips the first getLine after 3 seconds, but when it gets to second getLine I have to enter my input twice. Any advice?

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "x:"
  x <- timeout 3000000 getLine
  putStrLn "y:"
  y <- getLine
  putStrLn y
```

Comment: So you want the `getLine` to happen regardless, only its output will be ignored after 3s. One way is to have an auxiliary thread that reads the lines, and puts them in `MVar`s provided by the main thread. An evil way is to use lazy IO.

Comment: Could not reproduce. When I wait 3 s, type 30, and press enter, it immediately prints 30 and exits.

Comment: Well, I wait 3 s, type 30 and I have to type 30 again to print it and exit.

Comment: I, too, am unable to reproduce on Linux, either via a GHC-compiled executable or run from "GHCi".  Provided I wait long enough for the "y:" prompt to appear (i.e., about 3 seconds), I only need to type 30<Enter> once, and the program echoes it back and exits.  What platform are you running this on, and are you running it as a standalone compiled executable or under GHCi?

Comment: I tested it on Windows, using ghc compiled exe.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but...

I can confirm the behavior on Windows.  The prompt "x:" appears, then after 3 seconds, the prompt "y:" appears, but the first line of input is ignored.  If the program is compiled with `-threaded`, the "y:" prompt never appears until the first line is entered.  (The timeout is still "processed" in the sense that the value of `x` will be `Nothing` if the first line is entered after the timeout, but either way, only the second line of input is processed for `y <- getLine`.)

I think the underlying issue may be the problems with interrupting I/O via asynchronous exceptions under Windows, as documented in [issue #7353](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/7353).  The bug report there makes it sound like only the threaded runtime is affected, but I think it's an issue whether the threaded or non-threaded runtime is used.  The implementation of `timeout` has a special code path for handling the Windows threaded runtime, which may explain the differences in behavior, even though in both cases the runtime is failing to cancel the first `getLine`.

There is ongoing work on a native [Windows I/O Manager](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/merge_requests/1224) that is supposed to address issue #7353 among many other problems with I/O under Windows.  I don't have a Windows build machine that I can try to build/test it on, though, to see if it addresses this specific problem.